# Async await throwing error when writing login route. What could be the issue, here is the login route?

Tags: node.js

Async await throwing error when writing login route. What could be the issue, here is the login route?
I have looked at bcrypt documentation but I have still failed to figure out how to solve this.

```
// Login a User
    router.post('/login', async(req, res) => {
        User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
            .then(user => {
                if(!user){
                    res.send(`User with email not ${req.body.email} found`)
                }else{
                
            const checkPassword = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)
            // let checkPassword;

            console.log(checkPassword)
            if(!checkPassword){
                res.send('entered wrong password not found')
            }else{
                res.send('Success, you are logged')
            }
        }
        
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })    
})
```

and the error...

```
const checkPassword = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)
                                      ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\PROJECTS\APIS\REVIEWRR\backend\server.js:11:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! apis@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the apis@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\E6440\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-30T10_20_46_382Z-debug.log
```

Comment: If you look at the function that contains `bcrypt.compare()`, it is the callback you pass to `.then()` and that is not declared as `async`.   Also, please fix the visible indentation for the code in your question and some of this will be more obvious to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact error message you get tells you what to look for.  If you look at the function that contains `bcrypt.compare()`, it is the callback you pass to `.then()` and that is not declared as `async`.

But, there's a better way to write this, since you don't typically want to mix `await` and `.then()`.  Pick one model or the other for any given piece of code:

```
// Login a User
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});
        if (!user) {
            res.send(`User with email not ${req.body.email} found`)
        } else {
            const checkPassword = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)
            console.log(checkPassword)
            if (!checkPassword) {
                res.send('entered wrong password not found')
            } else {
                res.send('Success, you are logged')
            }
        }
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        // you can also send a response body here if you want
        // with res.status(500).send(someErrorMessage or Object);
        // But, you must always send a response of some type
        res.sendStatus(500);     
    }
});
```

Note:  I also added a `res.sendStatus(500);` in the error handling since you always need to send a response to the request, even if there's an error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `async` in one line.

`.then(async user => {`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using more simplified syntax `async-await`

You are doing comparison without async function

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
try {
  const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
  if (!user) {
    res.status(404).send(`User with email not ${req.body.email} found`)
  } else {
    const checkPassword = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    // let checkPassword;
    console.log(checkPassword)
    if (!checkPassword) {
      res.status(401).send('entered wrong password not found')
    } else {
      res.status(200).send('Success, you are logged')
    }
  }

} catch (error) {
  res.status(500).send(error);
}
});
```

Comment: There's no error handling here if `User.findOne()` or `bcrypt.compare()` rejects that sends an appropriate error response.  `await`nearly always needs to be surrounded with `try/catch` in order to handle possible errors.

Comment: `catch` will handle errors. @Edgar256 will handle these errors in his code.

Comment: Why mix `await` and `.catch()` when you could catch all errors in one place with `try/catch`?  You also still aren't sending an error response in either `.catch()`.

Comment: I made as per your requested changes @jfriend00 Thanks.

Comment: worked like magic, thanks @Prathamesh More

Comment: Please accept my answer to help the community! @Edgar256